# Indexing a batch of images using PyTorch tensor from an index image

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, torch

Suppose I have a batch of images `M` in the form of a torch tensor `(B, W, H)`, and an image `I` of size `(W, H)` whose pixels are indices.

I want to get an image `(W, H)` where each pixel come from the corresponding image in the image batch (following the indexing of `I`).

**Example**

Given `M` of shape `(3, 4, 8)`:

```
tensor([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
         [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
         [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
         [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]],

        [[-2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
         [-2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
         [-2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
         [-2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.]]])
```

and `I` of shape `(4, 8)`:

```
tensor([[2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

the resulting image would be:

```
tensor([[-2.,  0., -2.,  0., -1.,  0., -1.,  0.],
        [-2., -2., -1.,  0.,  0., -2., -1.,  0.],
        [-2.,  0.,  0., -2., -1., -1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0., -2.,  0., -2., -1.]])
```

**Note 1**

I don't care about the ordering of the `M` dimensions, it could be `(W, H, B)` as well if it provides an easier solution.

**Note 2**

I am also interested in a NumPy solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

```py
indices = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(I.shape[0]), torch.arange(I.shape[1]))
result = M[I, *indices]
```

or using numpy:

```
indices = np.indices(I)
result = M[I, indices[0], indices[1]]
```